# Where I could find an explation about use the word "or" in the signature of a java method?

Tags: java, methods, java-8, interface, method-reference

I have to explain my subject because I don't know how to search this on google... I need just a hint.

I'm doing a tutorial of Java about Reference Methods and Lamdba. "How to filter a person in a list of people". I'm not worried about how I can do it but where I can find and explanation about what is
this contruction **" filterName.or"** and  this other in the interface **"default public Filter or (Filter filtro) {"**

**" filterName.or"**, this is an Interface.or

**"default public Filter or (Filter filtro) {"** I think this is a method with no name because is like a functional interface and no need name for the method but ¿how to use **OR**...?

and I have find this construction:

```
public class MainDF {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
}

public static void test() {

    Filter filterName = new FiltroName();
    Filter filterAge = new FilterAge();

    // I've never seen this, an interface with and or
    Filter otherFilterName = filterName.or( filterAge );

    Persona persona = new Persona("Michael", 18);

    filterName.testear(persona);

    otherFilterName.testear(persona);

}

}
```

And the interface that use is this one:

```
import data.Persona;

public interface Filter {

public boolean testear( Persona persona );

// I can't understand how this works, Filter is the type return but 
// how it works the combination of Filter or (Filter filter)
default public Filter or (Filter filtro) {

    System.out.println("entrando en default...");

    return (Persona p)->{
        return testear(p) || filtro.testear(p);
    };

}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly. The `or` here is just a method name. And you call it like any other method.

Comment: Unusual code, but `or` is not a keyword or a conjunction here. It's a method name. It could just as well be called `test_with_or`. `public Filter or (Filter filtro)` means that `or` is a method, it takes a `Filter`, and it returns a `Filter`. Imagine it written as `public Filter test_with_or(Filter filtro)` (without the confusing whitespace).

Comment: Ok,I understand now... I couldn't see it. I was thinking everytime that OR it was and opererator and thinking "What is this?" Thank to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

Unusual code, but `or` is not a keyword or a conjunction here. It's a method name. It could just as well be called `test_with_or`. The code:

```
public Filter or (Filter filtro) {
    // ...
}
```

more commonly written as (without the confusing whitespace):

```
public Filter or(Filter filtro) {
    // ...
}
```

means that `or` is a method, it takes a `Filter`, and it returns a `Filter`. Imagine it written as:

```
public Filter test_with_or(Filter filtro) {
    // ...
}
```